# Can't change llvmpipe graphics on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, 20.10

I recently bought **RX580** I'm on **i3-7100**, Ubuntu was working fine with intel HD graphics on RX580, but I tried installing AMD driver for Ubuntu 20.04 and now it's stuck on `llvmpipe` graphics. can't change to intel graphics. I tried changing `grub` configuration with nouveau.modeset=0 but it didn't work. AMD has no driver support for 20.10 yet. so I'm stuck on `llvmpipe` graphics. any solutions?